# @print starting half way down page

Tags: css, printing

I am setting up @print media queries but whatever I do my page looks great in the pdf preview but when I print it out it starts half way down the page? So the first half of the page is simply missing on the printed document. It is not being cut when a new div starts but half way through a div.

There is a also a lot of empty white space at the bottom of the printed page. I have set the width but have no idea how to fix this? Here is the @print code that is within the external css sheet:

```
    @media print{
#nav-bar-upper, .nobr, #contact-and-follow, #blower-mob, #SkypeButton_Call_darrenmortonphotography, #back-to-top-div, #facebook-div{display: none;}
#upper-section{height: 100px;}
#print-website, #print-phone{display: block; text-align: center;}
.title-left{text-decoration: underline;}
h1, h2, h3, p, li, .title-left{color: black; font 12pt "helvetica"}

body, #main-container, #upper-section, #lower-section {width: 80%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
@page{margin-left: 1cm; margin-right: 1cm; margin-bottom: 0; padding: 0;}  
}
```

Any ideas what would cause this and how to fix it? I have searched all over the place but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this with chrome and it turned out it was because I was using `display:table` for some of my containing elements

Comment: @Pete, hmm interesting, I am not using table on this site so it will not be that. Annoying thing is that I can only tell if I am closer to a fix once the page is printed as the preview looks great! I could change every element until I isolate the problem but to much paper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out what the problem was and am posting it here in case anyone else has the same issues. Totally stupid and therefore the last thing I thought about! The printer settings were wrong! I found out when I tried to print from another web page and it printed the same way as my site did. I had a closer look at my printers settings and after changing things around my page now prints fine! Hope this helps someone from wasting about 4 hours like I did trying to work this out!